# Location to store temporary data in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, session-variables

I have an application where I am required to store the data for some time and use it later.After I am done using data I don't need it anymore(that is why I avoided storing in the database).

Basically, I have test management system in which student will appear for the test which allows only one attempt for a given test. So, when a student starts the test and starts answering questions, I want to save the answers right way (after user answer each question rather than waiting until the end of the test(that's the requirement of my system and I won't be able to change)) on the server somewhere(which I can use to calculate the score later once the student has submitted test). I am confused where can I store this temporary answers from the student(I say it as temporary because I don't need it after I calculate the score).

I thought of saving it in session variables and remove it when I am done using it. Is it the right approach? or Spring MVC provide any context where I can store data and remove it later. Thank in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Store the temporary answers in db and possibly delete them when you calculate the score. Do not use session, if server goes down or client browser crashes, answered questions could be lost.